# Octave: How can I vectorize this for-lop?

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization, octave

Can this for-loop be vectorized?
I want to be able to vectorize the for-loop of this code to obtain a matrix like "sample". Trying to vectorize I got the "sample2" matrix, however as you can see it does not show the values I want for each row due to the linear index when I take "data" as a matrix instead of as a vector.

```
close all; clear all; clc;
N=5; n=10; n1=2; n2=8;
rand('state', sum(100*clock));  
choose=round(((n-1)*rand(N,n))+1);
data=choose.^2;
idx=choose(:,n1:n2);
for i=1:N
dat=data(i,:); 
sample(i,:)=dat(idx(i,:));
end

%Trying to vectorize to get the same result
sample2(:,(n1:n2)-n1+1)=data(idx);
```

Results:

```
data =
36    64    64    25    81     4   100    36    49    25
 4     4     1    16     4    16    81    16   100    64
36    81    36    25    16    16     1    64    49     4
36    64    49    49    25    36   100    64    81    64
 1    16    16    49    64    49    81     4    16    64

idx =
8    8    5    9    2   10    6
2    1    4    2    4    9    4
9    6    5    4    4    1    8
8    7    7    5    6   10    8
4    4    7    8    7    9    2

sample =
36    36    81    49    64    25     4
 4     4    16     4    16   100    16
49    16    16    25    25    36    64
64   100   100    25    36    64    64
49    49    81     4    81    16    16

sample2 =
81   81    1   64    4   16   64
4    36   36    4   36   64   36
64   64    1   36   36   36   81
81    4    4    1   64   16   81
36   36    4   81    4   64    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to index row major.  But Octave indexes column major.  You can transpose your input to get the indicies right.  Also, if you want to index into the second col, you can just add the length of the first column.

Try this:

```
data2 = data';
sample2 = data2([idx + [0:size(idx,1)-1]'*size(data,2)])
```

First line just transposes the matrix so you get what would be row indexing of the original.

Second line modifies the index matrix to be total index instead of row index by adding the length of the original data rows, then references the data to provide the result.